# Table layout with column width restrictions

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a problem with a HTML table with 3 columns.
Restrictions:

- column 1: fixed width, no wrap (small text)
- column 2: longer text wrap possible
- column 3: descriptive long text, wrap
- a row should span the entire width of the page (due to background coloring)
- column 3 should have a minimum width of 70%
- column 2 should take as much space as possible but keeping the restriction about column 3 in consideration (so should, more or less, be maximal 30%).

The following code gives a result that looks OK:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table >
  <tr style="background-color:red;color:blue;">
    <td style="width:100px;">Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td style="min-width:70%;width:100%;">50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr >
    <td style="width:100px;">Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td style="min-width:70%;width:100%;">94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:100px;">John</td>
    <td >Doe</td>
    <td style="min-width:70%;width:100%;">80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

But when replacing the text in the second column of the second row (i.e. Jackson) by a longer text e.g.

> Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
>   accusantium doloremque laudantium,

it does  not look good anymore, the second column is small and I see no way to make it wider.

Comment: At downvoter, what is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `width:100%` to the third column makes the `min-width:70%` ineffective, instead make the whole table full width, changes are shown below:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr style="background-color:red;color:blue;">
        <td style="width:100px;">Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td style="min-width:70%;">50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr >
        <td style="width:100px;">Eve</td>
        <td>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,</td>
        <td style="min-width:70%;">94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:100px;">John</td>
        <td >Doe</td>
        <td style="min-width:70%;">80</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when I now change the "sed..." example is OK, but when replacing the entire "Sed .." with just e.g. the word "Jackson" the second column stays at this width with "white space, actually I would i this case like to have that the second column is smaller (Just the width of the word "Jackson").

Comment: Then I'm afraid that the expected result can't be achieved with pure css and table layouts. It should be doable with css grid - are you required to support older browsers, or would css grid be a viable option?

Comment: What are "old" browsers? Actually the code is intended for doxygen. I don't know anything about "css grid", so I'm interested. (in the mean time I will also check some documentation about css grid).

Comment: For browser support of any feature I highly recommend [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/). When i comes to [css grid](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) by "old" browsers I mean IE<10 (or IE at all, depending how advanced grid features you want) and Safari<10.1. And when it comes to doxygen, then adding css styling would have effect only on HTML output, so LaTeX, Man pages, RTF, XML and Docbook formats would be left out.

Comment: I'm well aware of that in doxygen it is only is for HTML (I know some of the internals ;-) ),  it is just for certain HTML pages it is needed. I think the limitation on the browser versions is at the moment a bit to strict for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is probably a non-starter, but you don't necessarily need to use tables for this kind of thing.

If I were making this page I'd  skip the table and start with the the [Three Column Liquid Layout](https://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm) by Mathew Taylor.... and then swap columns two and three.